# "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" what's missing?

Tags: python, syntax-error

I just start using Python 3.7 and I'm working on the IDLE, using the code below, but everytime I click "run" and try to create a new Data Frame adding multiple csv, i get the INVALID SYNTAX error and the word "archivos" marked :(

```
def CREA_DATA_FRAME_dias(archivos, fechas, ts):

    for a in range(len(archivos)):
        if a == 0:
            df, eje = CREA_DATA_FRAME(archivos[a], fechas[a], ts)
        else:
            dfN, ejeN = CREA_DATA_FRAME(archivos[a], fechas[a], ts)

            df = pd.concat([df, dfN])
            eje.extend(ejeN)

    return df, eje
```

This is what I typed in the Shell:

````
>>> df, eje = CREA_DATA_FRAME_dias(archivos, fechas, 5)\
 \
    archivos = ["C:/Users/Desktop/FILES/01-04-2018.csv",
            "C:/Users/Desktop/FILES/02-04-2018.csv",
            "C:/Users/Desktop/FILES/03-04-2018.csv",
            "C:/Users/Desktop/FILES/04-04-2018.csv",
            "C:/Users/Desktop/FILES/05-04-2018.csv"]
    fechas = ["2018-04-01","2018-04-02","2018-04-03","2018-04-04","2018-04-05"]```

SyntaxError: Invalid Syntax
````

Comment: Don't forget to tag your question with the language you're using, this helps ensure it will get seen by the proper people.

Comment: Are those triple quotes "```" at the end of the `fechas` line real?

Comment: should not you define `archivos` and `fechas` first before calling them ?

Comment: Set `archivos` and `fechas` before calling function. `>>> archivos = ...`, `>>> fechas = ...`, `>>> df, eje = CREA_DATA_FRAME_dias(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you really mean

```py
aaa = ["C:/Users/Desktop/FILES/01-04-2018.csv",
        "C:/Users/Desktop/FILES/02-04-2018.csv",
        "C:/Users/Desktop/FILES/03-04-2018.csv",
        "C:/Users/Desktop/FILES/04-04-2018.csv",
        "C:/Users/Desktop/FILES/05-04-2018.csv"]
fff = ["2018-04-01","2018-04-02","2018-04-03","2018-04-04","2018-04-05"]
foo, bar = CREA_DATA_FRAME_dias(aaa, fff, 5)
```

where I have systematically renamed all variables, just to highlight that variable names outside the `def` are unrelated to variables inside it, and vice versa.

This can equivalently be written without explicit variables for the parameters;

```
foo, bar = CREA_DATA_FRAME_dias(
   ["C:/Users/Desktop/FILES/01-04-2018.csv",
    "C:/Users/Desktop/FILES/02-04-2018.csv",
    "C:/Users/Desktop/FILES/03-04-2018.csv",
    "C:/Users/Desktop/FILES/04-04-2018.csv",
    "C:/Users/Desktop/FILES/05-04-2018.csv"],
   ["2018-04-01","2018-04-02","2018-04-03","2018-04-04","2018-04-05"], 5)
```

Perhaps this could be refactored along the lines of

```
def CREA_DATA_FRAME_dias(fechas_y_archivos, ts):
    dfs = []
    ejes = []
    for fecha, archivo in fechas_y_archivos:
        df, eje = CREA_DATA_FRAME(archivo, fecha, ts)
        dfs.append(df)
        ejes.append(eje)
    return pd.concat(dfs), ejes
```

and then you'd call it like

```
foo, bar = CREA_DATA_FRAME_dias(
   {"2018-04-01": "C:/Users/Desktop/FILES/01-04-2018.csv",
    "2018-04-02": "C:/Users/Desktop/FILES/02-04-2018.csv",
    "2018-04-03": "C:/Users/Desktop/FILES/03-04-2018.csv",
    "2018-04-04": "C:/Users/Desktop/FILES/04-04-2018.csv",
    "2018-04-05": "C:/Users/Desktop/FILES/05-04-2018.csv"}, 5)
```

Comment: Probably the Pandas part could be made more elegant still; I'm not really familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the semicolon or newline separating the statements you typed into the shell (newlines don't count if they follow the backslash `\`). Try entering one statement at a time. Also, shouldn't you define `archivos` and `fechas` before you use them as arguments? Python is an imperative language, so the statements are executed in the order written.

Comment: Thank u so much guys!! Indeed, I HAVE to define "Archivos" / "Fechas" before calling them, what a noobie mistake, i'm still learning, thank you again!